# Cloud Run, Cloud Build suddenly failed (token expired)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

```
creating bucket if not exists: getting bucket "abc_cloudbuild": Get "https://storage.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/abc_cloudbuild?alt=json&prettyPrint=false&projection=full": oauth2: cannot fetch token: 400 Bad Request

Response: {
  "error": "invalid_grant",
  "error_description": "Token has been expired or revoked."
}
```

My dev tool is GoLand(Intelli J)

Suddenly I can`t upload my source code to GCP!!

Sign in setting is already done in my tool

---

I signed out, I can not even login right now Go land doesn`t recognize that I log in (I`m done with Google Signin on Google Signin web page that pops up)

Background Tasks

`Sign in via the opend browser...` infinite processing

Comment: component upgrade is worked. but I think Google needs to fix it in future

Comment: Please post your answer if this is resolved so that other community members will find this helpful.